# Как найти индекс в массиве Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получить индекс заданного числа в массиве целочисленного типа? К примеру, вывести на консоль индекс числа 1 или 7, если они есть в массиве. Я так понимаю, что через if?

Answer (score 5):

```
s = [3,4,1,2,5]
print(s.index(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно пройтись по массиву циклом for, если данный элемент - тот, который нам нужен, пишем break и выводим индекс. Работает за O(n).

Comment: Добавьте тогда пример, чтобы не был голый текст, например: `def index(items, value): for i, x in enumerate(items): if x == value: return i` это после цикла: `return -1`. После пример использования: `s = [3,4,1,2,5]` `print(index(s, 1))`